# How to import JSON Simple in Eclipse?

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I am trying to import JSON Simple into my java project that I am developing with Eclipse.

My problem is that whatever I do, I get this error when calling the class that uses JSON Simple:

*"Exception in thread" AWT-EventQueue-0 "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org / json / simple / JSONObject"*

However, I did add the library by going to the properties of my project / Java Build Path / Librairies / Add External JARs

All the tutorials I came across do nothing more and it works ...

I tried to move the jar file, but whether it is in a lib folder at the root of the project or on the desktop it doesn't change anything.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.*;

public class JSONSimple {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void writePlayers(Player[] players){

        JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject();
        JSONArray playerList = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject player;
        JSONArray scoreList;

        for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            player = new JSONObject();

            player.put("pseudo", players[i].getPseudo());

            scoreList = new JSONArray();
            for(int j = 0; j < players[i].getNextLevelToPass()-1; j++) {
                scoreList.add(players[j].getLevelScore(j));
            }
            player.put("scoreList", scoreList);

            player.put("nextLevelToPass", players[i].getNextLevelToPass());

            playerList.add(player);
        }

        obj.put("playerTab", playerList);

        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some test, when you're in "Java Build Path/Libraries" you need to import the external libraries in "Classpath" not "Modulepath". I did that and it work now.